# Spring to read environment based properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

I have a spring project (not spring boot), in where I have 3 environment based properties files and 1 main property file.
application.properties is read on every startup, but I would like to have application-dev.properties read when I run application with -Denv=dev.

I run the appliaction with gradle tomcatRunWar with following configuration:
[run configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCeAl.png)

And my commonContext.xml is setup like this:

```
  <bean id="configProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ">
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
<property name="locations">
  <list>
    <value>classpath:conf/application.properties</value>
    <value>classpath:conf/application-#{systemProperties['env']}.properties</value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
<property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
```

But in logs it just says "conf/application-.properties cannot be opened because it does not exist", so it doesn't read value that I've set with -Denv=dev.

I have read some other threads, but didn't see a problem like this there. 
Setting environment variables works, but that's not an option to use.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
<value>classpath:conf/application-${env}.properties</value>
```

Any system parameters are automatically added to the environment.

Comment: Thx for reply, but this doesn't even try to read anything currently.
Could not load properties from class path resource [conf/application-${env}.properties]: class path resource [conf/application-${env}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: @TaaviKivimaa then you are not setting the environment variable correctly, the above syntax is correct see [here](http://www.summa.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help, I found out the problem was that with IntelliJ the property set in run configuration wasn't accessible in code, but running it with gradle, it was accessible.